# Running Java EE 7 on Tomcat 7 in Netbeans

Tags: tomcat, java-ee-6, java-ee-7, jersey-2.0

I'm not able to run a Java EE 7 webapp on tomcat 7 while in Eclipse using the same tomcat server it works. I can find my tomcat 7 server if I change the following in my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

If i change it to 6.0 it works fine in Netbeans but the problem is I'm using Jersey for my Rest API and at client side I use:

```
new Gson().fromJson(resp.readEntity(String.class), User.class);
```

But it doesn't know the method readEntity anymore and I only have the option using the getEntity method but I can't get it to work and I refuse to change all my code...

It's working in Eclipse and not complaining... Netbeans fault I think
Ok weird thing is Tomcat 7 doesn't support Java EE 7. How come this is working in Eclipse with no problems?

Comment: Apache Tomcat 7 only supports 3.0 Servlet, which is EE 6, see the release notes at [this link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RELEASE-NOTES.txt).

Comment: Yes, I know. I can't use glassfish, I'll always need to deploy on a tomcat 7. I think the problem lies with Jersey. maybe I need to downgrade but I don't want to change too much code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, it's Jersey fault. I changed to java--ee 6 version in pom and some dependencies fixes with Jersey.